# Return all columns + a few more in a UDF used by the map function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using a map function to generate a new column where its value depends on the result of a column that already exists in the dataframe.

```py
def computeTechFields(row):
    if row.col1!=VALUE_TO_COMPARE:
            tech1=0
    else:
            tech1=1
    return (row.col1, row.col2, row.col3, tech1)

delta2rdd = delta.map(computeTechFields)
```

The problem is that my main dataframe has more than 150 columns that I have to return with the map function so in the end I have something like this :

```py
return (row.col1, row.col2, row.col3, row.col4, row.col5, row.col6, row.col7, row.col8, row.col9, row.col10, row.col11, row.col12, row.col13, row.col14, row.col15, row.col16, row.col17, row.col18 ..... row.col149, row.col150, row.col151, tech1)
```

As you can see, it is really long to write and difficult to read. So I tried to do something like this :

```py
return (row.*, tech1)
```

But of course it did not work.

I know that the "withColumn" function exists but I don't know much about its performance and could not make it work anyway.

**Edit (What happened with the withColumn function) :**

```py
def computeTech1(row):
    if row.col1!=VALUE_TO_COMPARE:
            tech1=0
    else:
            tech1=1
    return tech1

delta2 = delta.withColumn("tech1", computeTech1)
```

And it gave me this error :

```py
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

I tried to do something like this :

```py
return col(tech1)
```

The error was the same

I also tried :

```py
delta2 = delta.withColumn("tech1", col(computeTech1))
```

This time, the error was :

```py
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

**End of the edit**

So my question is, how can I return all the columns + a few more within my UDF used by the map function ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you elaborate on how `withColumn` did not work? Because it sounds like you want to exactly do what that function is for.

Comment: Just a question, you will append that tech if there is at least one of your columns with that value?

Comment: @LiMuBei Sorry that I did not explain what happened with "withColumn". I edited my question with the code that I tried and the error that I get to make it more understansable.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto The tech columns (there will be 4 of them in the end) will be added each time. This is their value (0 or 1) that will be different based of the value of the other columns.

Comment: @JackWenger But it is a `DataFrame` right? Let say that this df has 10000 columns and it has that magic value in one of these columns, so we append that value at the end? Is that what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not super firm with Python, so people might correct me on the syntax here, but the general idea is to make your function a UDF with a column as input, then call that inside `withColumn`. I used a lambda here, but with some fiddeling it should also work with a function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

computeTech1UDF = udf(
   lambda col: 0 if col != VALUE_TO_COMPARE else 1, IntegerType())

delta2 = delta.withColumn("tech1", computeTech1UDF(col1))
```

What you tried did not work since you did not provide `withColumn` with a column expression (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn). Using the UDF wrapper achieves exactly that.

Comment: Thank you ! It actually worked with the lambda but I could not manage to make it work with a regular function. The problem is with the condition : `def computeTech1UDF(col1): if col1 != VALUE_TO_COMPARE: tech1 = lit(0) else: tech1 = lit(1) return tech1` I always get this error : `Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.`